# Delete and insert statement

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to SQL, so I face a problem when am using delete statement then insert statement the row that I deleted is replaced by the row that I will insert, for example:

Before deleting a row

Table:

```
Count | Username | Time 
------+----------+------
  10  | MMMMM    | 20:00
  11  | UUUUU    | 23:00
  12  | NNNNN    | 23:30
```

Code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from table where [Count] = 11", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

After deleting a row:

```
Count | Username | Time
------+----------+------
  10  | MMMMM    | 20:00
  12  | NNNNN    | 23:30
```

Code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into table values (13,'SSSSS', '01:00')", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

After inserting a row:

```
Count | Username | Time
------+----------+------
  10  | MMMMM    | 20:00
  13  | SSSSS    | 01:00
  12  | NNNNN    | 23:30
```

This the problem in the previous table after using insert statement, if there is a way to make it look like this table after using insert statement :

```
Count | Username | Time
------+----------+------
  10  | MMMMM    | 20:00
  12  | NNNNN    | 23:30
  13  | SSSSS    | 01:00
```

**Update**

I forget to use primary key and it worked for me, i tried to use `order by` and it didn't help me

Comment: What dbms are you using? What is your primary key? Can't you just order by count when getting the results from the database?

Comment: All you need is `order by`

Comment: Most databases are unsorted by default. Do NOT assume a `SELECT` without specifying an `ORDER BY` to have a specific order of results

Comment: Thanks for helping me @ivar

Comment: Thanks GiladGreen  and you Sentry but it didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT [Count], Username, Time
FROM Table
ORDER BY [Count]
```

ORDER BY is what you're looking for here. There is no order that can safely be assumed without specifying it directly.

Comment: Even with a primary key, if you do not use ORDER BY you are not guaranteed any particular order. If it happens that you are receiving the correct order, you cannot always count on that without using ORDER BY. This is because SQL is using set based operations. If you are expecting a particular order, you should always use ORDER BY.

Comment: Does (`order by`) sort `Count` column by its defined data type even if this row will not be selected to show in the `DGV` ?

Comment: Yes it does. What is the data type? Int?

Comment: Yes, it is `int`

Comment: And how would you like to sort it? If low to high, you can say ORDER BY [Count]. If high to low, you can say ORDER BY [Count] DESC. The reason for the brackets around Count is because count is a reserved keyword, so we need to tell it we mean the column instead of the keyword.

Comment: Thankful for your detailed answer, so can i use this SELECT statement `Select [Username],[Time] From Table ORDER BY [Count]` and the `DGV` would be ordered ?

Comment: The results of the query will be sorted and if you are not doing anything to change the sorting in the data grid view you will be good to go.